# Tracking a single page on another domain in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have access to edit a 'mini-site' hosted on our organisation's parent site. I'd like to track this page using Google Analytics, however I don't have access to the front page so I can't verify this as my domain.

Using the tracking code for our main site works, however I don't want this data to be confused with similarly named pages on our site (for example, our mini-site is at /radio, and if we had a /radio at our main site this would be counted as the same).

Has anyone been in this situation before? I'd like to just redirect visitors to our mini-site to our main site, seeing as it ranks higher in Google, but I've been told to maintain a separate site with our main features.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they do. You will have to add different domains in your google analytics account. You can add DNS TXT  to your subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

I think this Google support "[Tracking Multiple Domains](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingSite.html)" article will point you in the right direction

To quote:-

"Tracking Across iFrames"

"In a site where the transfer between domains is done by opening a new window or by including content in an iFrame, you will need to to use the _getLinkerUrl() method to transfer visitor and campaign cookies from one domain to another. For example, suppose you include a form in an iFrame that is hosted on www.my-example-iframecontent.com. In order to transfer visitor information from the parent page that hosts the iFrame on www.example-parent.com, you would use JavaScript to load the iFrame and pass in the cookie information using the _getLinkerURL() method."

Numerous other instances are listed in the article, hopefully one will match your circumstances.