# How to monitor traffic on a single page that I control when I don't control the domain?

Tags: domains, google-analytics, referrer

I have a webpage like

```
www.site.com/myaccount/foo/index.htm
```

I have complete control over the HTML on this page (e.g., I can insert a script).
However, I have no control over the rest of the site.
**update:** Note that I only want to have information on traffic to the page under my control. I have no interest in the traffic for the rest of the site.
I'd particularly like to get an idea of referring URLs to the page under my control.

- **Will Google Analytics work on a single page under my control?**
- **If not, are there other tools suited to monitoring traffic to a single page?**

Note I saw this [question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25536/tracking-a-single-page-on-another-domain-in-google-analytics) but it did not seem to answer my question. Also, I'm not tied to using Google Analytics if another online system would work.

Specifically, I have added the google analytics tracking code to the page, but am still getting the error

> Status: Tracking Not Installed 
>   The Google Analytics tracking code has not been detected on your
>   website's home page. For Analytics to function, you or your web
>   administrator must add the code to each page of your website.

This made me think that I might need to have access to `www.site.com/index.htm`

**Update:** After waiting another day, Google Analytics appears to have registered the tracking code. I presumably just had to wait a little longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to monitor rest of the website if you have got access to just one section of the website. Analytics can log visits/activities only if the script is triggered and from what you have mentioned I am gathering you won't be able to insert your script to rest of the pages.

To answer your questions:

**Will Google Analytics work on a single page under my control?**

Yes, it will work for one page you have control over.

For rest of the domain:

There are a number of external websites though which are going to provide you with some information on the domain you want to monitor (nowhere near as extensive as google analytics though).

alexa.com (will let you see how much traffic entire domain gets and what are the incoming search terms)

Comment: Thanks. I only want to monitor my single page. I'm still getting "tracking not installed" in Google Analytics. and the message "The Google Analytics tracking code has not been detected on your website's home page." I've added a little info to my question

Comment: Can you please 'view source' in your browser and see if the code you inserted is actually present there?

Comment: Hmm. Yes. it is there. But interestingly, I just noticed that there is also another google analytics script just above it. As a side note, I have edited a default page that presumably already contained an existing google analytics script. Perhaps that is the problem.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like your site administrator has already got a script running and perhaps disabled what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @JeromyAnglim Tracking code can be added by web servers too, like [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-outbound-rules-to-add-web-analytics-tracking-code) with IIS. But if you have access to the other script, you might be able to add your account to it - see [here](http://www.markinns.com/articles/full/adding_two_google_analytics_accounts_to_one_page)